# PHP ftp_nlist and ftp_rawlist produce same results?

Tags: php, iis-7

I have a little FTP client I'm writing for a job.  We're on a linux box - and the FTP server that I'm querying to is IIS 7.5.

What I'm running into, however, is that ftp_rawlist (which is what I want to use) isn't proffering up any more information than ftp_nlist does.

Both produce:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(54) "09-08-15  01:55PM               260187 firstdayvpk.jpg"
  [1]=>
  string(48) "09-08-15  02:41PM            556373631 globe.psd"
}
```

The code works when I run it to query from another LAMP server (meaning it gives the expanded/more detailed results).  Does anyone have any IIS insight (which is the only thing I can imagine) that would cause ftp_rawlist to produce the same truncated results as nlist?